# disable enable textbox based on dropdown selection asp.net javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, drop-down-menu

Happy friday everyone! 
I am trying to enable/disable textbox based on dropdown selection.
If dropdown selected index == 0 then the textbox should be enabled, otherwise it should be disabled.
Here is what I tried:

```
 <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="selection">
                            <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlWindSpeed" onchange="HideTextBox(this);" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="formField">
                                <asp:textbox id="txtActualWindSpeed" MaxLength="50" runat="server" />
                            </td>
```

and here is the JS function:

```
function HideTextBox(ddlId)
            {
             var ControlName = document.getElementById(ddlId.id);

             if(ControlName.value == 0)  //it depends on which value Selection do u want to hide or show your textbox
             {
                 document.getElementById('txtActualWindSpeed').style.display = '';

             }
             else
             {
                 document.getElementById('txtActualWindSpeed').style.display = 'none';

             }
        } 
                        </tr>
```

Using that I am getting this message:

**SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined**

Any idea what am I doing wrong?
Thanks, Laziale

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById('<%=txtActualWindSpeed.ClientID%>')`

Comment: Or have you tried adding ClientIDMode="Static" to the text boxes?

Comment: @Musa that is correct. Thanks. Please post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `document.getElementById('<%=txtActualWindSpeed.ClientID%>')`